# How to I set and recall a cookie then set a variable to the cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been trying to set up a username system in JS where you input a username through a prompt, and then a cookie gets set to the inputted username unless it's blank, where it rejects it. Once the website is reloaded it should recall the cookie and automatically set the username to the cookie without the prompt. I don't have a large understanding of how cookies work, so any help with this would be very helpful, thanks!
My code so far:

````
name: cookie.get('name');
  if(!name) {
    name: prompt('Choose a username:');
    if (!name) {
      alert('A real username please.');
    } else {
      cookie.set('name', name);
    }
  }
});```
````

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what is a cookie variable there. If you want to use native cookie API, you can use document.cookie, which gives you a string representation of the cookie. Otherwise, you can use some library which helps you to work with cookies. For example https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.
You could write:

```
let name = Cookies.get('name');
if(!name) {
    name = prompt('Choose a username:');
    if (!name) {
        alert('A real username please.');
    } else {
        Cookies.set('name', name);
    }
}
```

Or you can use localStorage since the username is not a sensitive data and it has a better API:

```
let name = localStorage.getItem('name');
if(!name) {
    name = prompt('Choose a username:');
    if(!name) {
        alert('A real username please');
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    }
}
```